# Using KNN to Find Optimal Value of K for Accuracy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, classification, knn

I'm a noob with KNN and trying to find the optimal value of k if we care most about mean accuracy across 4 folds. I know my optimal value is 12, but I keep getting an output of 7. Can someone help? Although my code runs, it doesn't produce expected output. BTW using Jupyter Notebooks. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the algorithm.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

# Load data
institutions_df = pd.read_csv('institutions.csv')
banklist_df = pd.read_csv('banklist.csv', encoding='cp1252')

# Merge the two dataframes based on the 'cert' key
merged_df = pd.merge(institutions_df, banklist_df, on='cert', how='left')

# Create 'failure' column indicating whether the bank has failed or not
merged_df["failure"] = merged_df["closing"].isnull().astype(int)

# Extract the relevant features and normalize them using min-max normalization
features = ['ASSET', 'DEP', 'DEPDOM', 'NETINC', 'OFFDOM', 'ROA', 'ROAPTX', 'ROE']
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
merged_df[features] = scaler.fit_transform(merged_df[features])

# Handle missing values using SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="constant", fill_value=0)
merged_df[features] = imputer.fit_transform(merged_df[features])

# Define the target variable (y) and features (X)
y = merged_df['failure']
X = merged_df[features]

# Define the range of k values to test
k_values = list(range(4, 19))

# Initialize variables to store results
accuracy_results = []

# Iterate over different values of k
for k in k_values:
    # Create a KNN classifier with the current value of k
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k)

    # Use KFold cross-validation to evaluate the classifier
    kfold = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=0)
    scores = cross_val_score(estimator=knn, X=X, y=y, cv=kfold)

    # Store mean accuracy for each k
    accuracy_results.append(scores.mean())

# Find the optimal k based on accuracy
optimal_k_accuracy = k_values[accuracy_results.index(max(accuracy_results))]

# Print the results
print(f"Optimal k for accuracy: {optimal_k_accuracy}")
```

Comment: `I know my optimal value is 12` How do you know that?

Comment: Print `accuracy_results` after the loop - either there's a duplicate, your assumption that 12 is optimal is incorrect, or there's noise that's masking it - i.e. try a different number of splits or consider if random is the best way to split the data (i.e. are your points independent).

Answer (score 0):

First things first, have you considered the fact that you may have more that one optimal value for k?

Otherwise, your code seems correct to me, although I'm not familiar with panda, I think at least the code from the line where you define `k_values` to the end is correct.

A good idea is always to print all your non-trivial objects (here maybe `accuracy_results`,`x`,`Y`, etc.) to clarify whether your code actually does what you want it to do...